# How to get the average price for the X most recent rows based on date?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, average

I am looking to calculate moving averages over variable dates.

My database is structured:

```
id int    
date date
price decimal
```

For example, I'd like to find out if the average price going back 19 days ever gets greater than the average price going back 40 days within the past 5 days. Each of those time periods is variable.

What I am getting stuck on is selecting a specific number of rows for subquery.

```
Select * from table
order by date
LIMIT 0 , 19
```

Knowing that there will only be 1 input per day, can I use the above as a subquery? After that the problem seems trivial....

Comment: You probably want to use `order by date DESC`

Answer (score 0):

if you only have one input per day you don't need id, date can be your primary id?  Am i missing something?  Then use select sum

```
SELECT SUM(price) AS totalPrice FROM table Order by date desc Limit (most recent date),(furthest back date) 

totalPrice/(total days)
```

I may not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use that as a sub-query like this:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(price) 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM t ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 10) AS t1;
```

This calculates the average price for the latest 10 rows.

[see fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9a696/8/0).